# Stop syncronizing an individual attribute with Azure AD Sync

Tags: microsoft-office-365, active-directory

Azure AD Sync is basically FIM with a PowerShell wrapper and two pre-configured Management Agents. Because of this, it's possible to stop synchronizing an attribute to AD using the FIM GUI that DirSync exposes. i.e. if I no longer want streetAddress to sync to the Office 365 tenant, I disable just that attribute in DirSync.

My question: Is this supported (i.e. documented on TechNet/MSDN anywhere) and are there certain attributes that are **required** for O365 to work other than userPrincipalName and DisplayName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 years later, this question is still shown in top Google results but O365 has changed a lot.
Now the list of attributes synchronized through AzureAD Connect can be found here (they can be filtered by application):

[Azure AD Connect sync: Attributes synchronized to Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-attributes-synchronized)

If you do not want to send a particular attribute to Azure, you can do this through the wizard, or  by following the procedure here:

[Azure AD Connect sync: How to make a change to the default configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-change-the-configuration#do-not-flow-an-attribute)

(see section **Do not flow an attribute**)

Answer (score 4):

I'm having trouble coming up with an official reference. (I'm not surprised, either...)

[This Wiki article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19901.dirsync-list-of-attributes-that-are-synced-by-the-azure-active-directory-sync-tool.aspx) enumerates a list of attributes required for objects to be "considered for sync". Quoth the article:

- cn
- member (applies only to groups)
- samAccountName (applies only to users)
- alias (applies only to groups and contacts)
- displayName (for groups with an mail or proxyAddresses attribute populated)

This seems to be further-corroborated by a [RMS team blog posting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rms/archive/2014/08/05/minsync.aspx) identifying the minimum attribute set necessary for Azure RMS. Obviously, you're not talking about Azure RMS, but I think it's reasonable to consider these attributes as at least partially overlapping with the list you're looking for.

- accountEnabled
- cn
- displayName
- mail
- member
- objectSid
- proxyAddresses
- pwdLastSet
- securityEnabled
- usageLocation
- userPrincipalName

Finally, I found [this community post](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/156588.aspx) wherein the poster talks about a minimum attribute-set that they came up with.

I'd like to say that I'm shocked that finding an official source for this information is difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I found at [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cbaa6539-5751-4b0f-a89c-87540d07a3e2/support-for-reducing-the-attribute-set-with-azure-active-directory-sync?forum=windowsazureaditpro) (basically, someone recommending your approach instead of Something Else):

> PS, it IS supported to deploy FIM and use whatever attributes you want, but thats a lot of work for your stated requirements...

That looks like a yes to me.

Like Evan, I'm having trouble finding much better.